# Movement of data from variables to registers in NASM programming

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

Following is the code for multiplying two numbers initialized in data section as "buff1" and "buff2". These are multiplied by successive addition method where buff1 is added buff2 times in rax register to give the result and it is later displayed through hex_ascii procedure using tempbuff variable.

```
%macro print 2
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall     
%endmacro
%macro accept 2
    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,0
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall
%endmacro
%macro exit 0
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
%endmacro

section .bss

    choice resb 2
    tempbuff resb 16    

section .data
    menu db 10,"1. Successive addition"
         db 10,"2. Add and Shift"
         db 10,"Enter the choice : "
    lenmenu equ $-menu

    after db 10,"Product is : "
    lenafter equ $-after

    buff1 dw 0AH
    buff2 dw 03H        

    newline db 0AH

section .code
global _start
_start:
    print menu,lenmenu

accept choice,2

    mov al,byte[choice]

case1:
    cmp al,31H
    jne case2
    print after,lenafter

    call succ_add
    jmp _start

case2:
    cmp al,32H
    jne case3
    call shift_add
    jmp _start

case3:
    exit
succ_add:
    mov rax,0H
    ;mov rcx,0H      ;Here is the problem
    ;mov cx,0H
    mov bx,[buff1]
    mov cx,[buff2]
    back0:
        add rax,rbx
    loop back0
    mov rbx,rax
    call hex_ascii
ret
hex_ascii:
    mov rcx,16
    mov rax,0H
    mov rsi,tempbuff
    back1:
        rol rbx,4   
        mov al,bl
        and al,0FH
        cmp al,09H  
        jbe add30
        add al,07H
        add30:
            add al,30H
        mov [rsi],al
        inc rsi
    loop back1
        print tempbuff,16
ret
shift_add:
    exit;code for this section not written yet
ret
```

In the above code inside the succ_add procedure, If I initialize rcx as 0, then my code is working properly(giving right result) ; but If I initialize cx register as 0 and then assign it as [buff2] then it is not giving me right result.
As the loop is running buff2 times (cx times), then what is the problem even when I initialize cx as 0 and than assign it [buff2] ?
Is there any difference when I initialize cx as 0 and rcx as 0 **in my code** ?
Also, another question is, Is there any way that I can assign a 2 byte sized variable into a 8 byte sized register ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoq4U.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 64-bit mode, loop uses rcx, not cx. Mov cx, [buff2] only writes cx—-the low 16 bits of rcx.

Use movzx ecx, word [buff2]. This initializes the entire register. (The low 16 bits are loaded with the contents of buff2 and the rest of the register is 0.) So you do not need mov rcx, 0 before it.

Comment: Note, you should also use movzx ebx, word [buff1].

Comment: So after movzx ecx,word[buff2] , the higher order bits except the space taken by content of buff2 is initialised with 0. Right ?

Comment: Suppose currently ecx is 00 05 00 00 . Now, if i write mov ecx ,word[k]
and [k] is 00 03 then what will be the final value of ecx ? Will the above instruction be wrong because both are of different size ? Also, if I now write mov cx,word[]k] instead of the above instruction then what will be the final value of ecx ? Must be 00 05 00 03. Right ?

Comment: You can’t write mov ecx, word [k]. The source and destination must be the same size. Yes, mov cx, [k] loads the low 16 bits of ecx and leaves the upper 16 bits unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying !!